How to serialize a list of Java Object to XML using javax.xml library with proper parent/child node names
I have a list called Documents that is comprised of different Document objects I created. I am trying to serialize the list to look like this:
<Documents>
   <Document>
   .
   .
   .
   </Document>
   <Document>
   .
   .
   .
   </Document>
</Documents>

This is is what I have in code:
    @XmlElementWrapper(name="Documents")
    @XmlElement(name = "Document")
    private Document[] documents;

But this is what its serializing to:
   <Documents>
       <Documents>
       .
       .
       .
       </Documents>
       <Documents>
       .
       .
       .
       </Documents>
    </Documents>

Where the children nodes have the same name as the parent node. IS there a way to get the desired outcome?

to ensures the XML is serialized correctly with proper parent and child node names you just need to modify the Document class to include a wrapper element for the list of documents. here is a test code so you get the point
Document Class
package com.stackoverflow.xmlserialization;

import jakarta.xml.bind.annotation.XmlElement;
import jakarta.xml.bind.annotation.XmlRootElement;
import jakarta.xml.bind.annotation.XmlType;
import java.util.List;

@XmlRootElement(name = "Documents")
@XmlType(name = "Document")
public class Document {
    private String title;
    private String content;
    private List<Document> documents;

    public Document() {
    }

    public Document(String title, String content) {
        this.title = title;
        this.content = content;
    }

    @XmlElement(name = "Title")
    public String getTitle() {
        return title;
    }

    public void setTitle(String title) {
        this.title = title;
    }

    @XmlElement(name = "Content")
    public String getContent() {
        return content;
    }

    public void setContent(String content) {
        this.content = content;
    }

    @XmlElement(name = "Document")
    public List<Document> getDocuments() {
        return documents;
    }

    public void setDocuments(List<Document> documents) {
        this.documents = documents;
    }
}

DocumentController Class
package com.stackoverflow.xmlserialization;

import jakarta.xml.bind.JAXBContext;
import jakarta.xml.bind.JAXBException;
import jakarta.xml.bind.Marshaller;
import org.springframework.web.bind.annotation.GetMapping;
import org.springframework.web.bind.annotation.RestController;

import java.io.StringWriter;
import java.util.Arrays;
import java.util.List;

@RestController
public class DocumentController {

    @GetMapping(value = "/documents", produces = "application/xml")
    public String getDocuments() {
        // Create a hardcoded list of Document objects
        List<Document> documents = Arrays.asList(
                new Document("Document 1 Title", "Document 1 Content"),
                new Document("Document 2 Title", "Document 2 Content")
        );

        // Create a wrapper Document object to hold the list
        Document wrapper = new Document();
        wrapper.setDocuments(documents);

        try {
            // Initialize JAXB context and marshaller
            JAXBContext context = JAXBContext.newInstance(Document.class);
            Marshaller marshaller = context.createMarshaller();
            marshaller.setProperty(Marshaller.JAXB_FORMATTED_OUTPUT, Boolean.TRUE);

            // Serialize to XML
            StringWriter sw = new StringWriter();
            marshaller.marshal(wrapper, sw);

            // Return the XML string
            return sw.toString();

        } catch (JAXBException e) {
            e.printStackTrace();
            return "<error>Error generating XML</error>";
        }
    }
}

I've test the /documents endpoint, and the returned xml is:
<Documents>
    <Document>
        <Content>Document 1 Content</Content>
        <Title>Document 1 Title</Title>
    </Document>
    <Document>
        <Content>Document 2 Content</Content>
        <Title>Document 2 Title</Title>
    </Document>
</Documents>

and this is the desired structure.
